# Como guardar contexto entre componentes

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-hooks

**Problema**: Tengo una función la cual mantiene siempre bien el `context`, el problema esta que al pasar de esa función de `react` a una componente de `react` se pierde y la página siguiente no es capaz de recuperar el `context`, aún así por alguna razón se me guarda el `context` en el `login.js` pero al ir a la otra componente y realizar un `static contexto = userContext`, lo termino perdiendo, además que dentro de la componente no se permite usar `React.useContext()`.

## `User.js`

```
import React from "react";

export const userContext = React.createContext('false');
export const setUserContext = React.createContext('false');
```

## `Login.js`

```
async function loginUser(credenciales, setUserInfo) {

  const url = "http://localhost:8000/api/Usuarios/?search=" + credenciales.usuario;
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  const data = await response.data;
  
  if(data.length > 0){ 

    if(data[0].password === credenciales.password){

      setUserInfo(data[0].nombre);

    }
    else{

      alert('Comprueba los datos introducidos');

    }
  }
  else{

    alert('Comprueba los datos introducidos');

  }
}

  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  const setUserInfo = React.useContext(setUserContext);
  
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = React.useState({});
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState({});

  console.log(userInfo);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    await loginUser({

      usuario,
      password,

    }, setUserInfo);
    
  };
```

## `CompraVenta.js`

Al realizar aquí en unas de las funciones `console.log(context)`, se mantiene de manera vacía.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {userContext} from "./user";

export default class Compraventa extends React.Component {
static context = userContext;
}
```

Comment: Algo que yo intentaría es colocar los hooks `useContext` y `useState` al inicio del componente `loginUser`, son [reglas básicas de los hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level), ¿tal vez el problema que describes sea por ese detalle? Además la lógica para obtener al usuario al inicio de `loginuser` debería ir en un hook `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que la mejor manera de ocupar los context es asi:

esto lo crearías en una carpeta llamada context y dentro de ella un archivo llamado user-context.js (la verdad q solo necesitas hacer el archivo con el nombre que te guste pero asi como yo te indico queda mas ordenado)

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function UserProvider(props){
    const [userContext, setuserContext] = useState(false);

    const cambiarValor = (value) => {
        return setuserContext(value);
    }

    const value = useMemo(() => {
        return({
            userContext,
            cambiarValor
        })
    }, [userContext]);

    return <UserContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />
}

export function useUser() {
    const context = React.useContext(UserContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useUser debe de estar dentro del proveedor userContext');
    }
    return context;
}
```

y en tu _app.js o en tu archivo principal aras lo siguiente:

```
import { UserProvider } from '../context/user-context';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
    <UserProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```